# Personalised Signatures for Shared Mailboxes in Office 365

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, exchange, email-signature

Yet again, I (well, myself and my minion) am/are being stymied by Office 365 Exchange. Everything is set up and working wonderfully. Well, almost everything. He/We have managed to get signatures set up for personal addresses that fill in the details using `%%FirstName%%` etc.

Now, what we want is to have emails sent from a shared mailbox to have a signature but to have that signature include the details of the user from whose account it was sent.

For example, UserA with the address `user.a@example.com` sends an email from DepartmentB, the address for which is `department.b@example.com`. The email is obviously sent through UserA's account because UserA has Send As permissions to that mailbox and arrives in its recipients inbox addressed from `department.b@example.com`.

How can I get the signature for DepartmentB to contain the First Name and Last Name of UserA if sent through UserA's account, and UserC's First Name and Last Name if sent through UserC's account?